# Incorrect size of label on viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, ios6, xib

I have following setup

- XIB file which has only landscape view. This view is connection to my controller
- There is a label on this view which is connected to `IBOutlet UILabel* label`
- This label is configured like this (it occupies the whole width of screen).
  [image]
- I overrided viewWillAppear and do this (to get the size of label).

> ```
> -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
> {
>     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
>
>     CGRect rect = _labelTitleLand.frame;
> }
> ```

The strange thing (which I don't understand). That it returns size = (width 768, height 21) when it launched in portrait (on iPad), which is correct.

And it returns size = (width 741 height 21) when it's launched in landscape. Which is weird. I anticipated that it will return width 1024, height 21 for landscape.

I was under impression that at the moment of viewWillAppear, all controls sizes are calculated already.

**Update 1**

If I check labelTitleLand.frame on viewDidAppear then it returns correct results. However, I don't like this, because I want to do some actions (based on this size) which influence how view will be drawn. In the case, if I will do it on viewDidAppear, as I understand there will be visible redrawing.

Comment: Try _labelTitleLand.bounds instead, and see if that works.

Comment: @rdelmar: It returns the same result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The layout of the view hierarchy has to be complete before you will get the actual final frames.

So you should check the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which will still be before the view hierarchy is actually drawn. If you need to make changes here you can without causing any redrawing to occur.

`viewWillAppear` is too early because this is before your autoresizing masks (and/or autolayout constraints) have had their effect.

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. BTW. Is there a good guide which describes this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a problem related to when a method is actually called at runtime.

I solved similar situation using

```
[self performSelector:@selector(checkMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

in viewWillAppear, and then:

```
- (void)checkMethod
{
    rect = _labelTitleLand.frame;
}
```

This gives your app the time needed to set its own frame.
It is not so elegant and it looks like a workaround, but it is very effective.

You can also try to force the frame of the UIView that is container of the UILabel in viewWillAppear like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f);

    CGRect rect = _labelTitleLand.frame;
}
```

But the first solution is more reliable and usually no lag is experienced.

Comment: The 100ms delay you introduce is in most cases probably enough for the layout to be complete. But rather than guess at that, you can just use the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method which is called exactly when the layout is complete, and before the views are on screen.

Comment: yes, of course, if the OP still need to support iOS4, then that isn't an option.

Comment: Frankly, both methods looks hack-ish. I rather go with viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: I think @Firoze Lafeer's answer is better too. But these methods can be helpful for targeting iOS 4.